# Как 16 колонок преобразовать в 12 колонок 960grid?

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

Всем привет!
Верстаю с использованием 960грид,использую 16 колонок,при 1600px экрана выводтся по 4 блока в ряд, как при 1200px выводить только 3 блока,при 1024px - 2 блока.
Как такое сделать?Можно ли при изменении шиирны браузера 16 колонок преобразовать в 12 колонок или как то по другому поступить?
[image]

http://test2.webjay.ru/

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Adapt.js, там для каждого разрешения можно указать файл со своей шириной блоков. http://adapt.960.gs/

Comment: ага,спасибо,но в этом случае они у меня будут просто подстраиваться под размер экрана, а мне надо чтобы исчезал 4-й блок при 1200px, и исчезали 3-й и 4-й блоки при 1024px.Это как реализовать?

Comment: 960gs из коробки такого не умеет. Надо назначать различные классы для каждой ширины экрана и в зависимости от ширины с помрщью @media они будут активироваться. В 960gs можно в adapt.js подтягивать свои файлы css для каждого разрешения - сделай в них нужную ширину и float элементов.